# How to pass a list of identifiers to the Hot Chocolate resolver method to reduce the number of database queries

Tags: c#, graphql

I'm using the Hot Chocolate library to build a GraphQL API in C#. I have

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Email Email { get; set; }

    public async Task<Email> GetEmailAsync(IResolverContext contex, [Service] UserService _userService)
    {
        var usersId = ...contex;
        var response = await _userService.GetUsersEmails(usersId);
        var email = response.First(e => Id == e.UserId);
        return email;
    }
}

public class Email
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
}
```

with a GetEmailAsync method that should fetch the emails of multiple users. I'm trying to pass a list of user IDs to the GetEmailAsync method to avoid multiple database queries. How can I pass this list of user IDs to the resolver method using Hot Chocolate? GetUsersEmails always return List.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do something like this

```
public async Task<List<Email>> GetEmailsAsync([Service] UserService _userService, IReadOnlyList<int> userIds)
{
    var response = await _userService.GetUsersEmails(usersIds);
    var emails = response.Select(e => Id == e.UserId);
    return emails.ToList();
}
```